# Typescript function with generic type in useState, allow nullable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have a hook function like this in React:

```js
export function useFetch<T = unknown|null>(url: string) : [T, boolean] {
  const accessToken = useAccessToken();
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>(null);  // TS ERROR
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (accessToken) {
      fetch(`/api/v1${url}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setData(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }, [accessToken, url]);
  return [data, isLoading];
}
```

But I get this error:
`Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'.ts(2345)`

How can I define T as nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T = unknown | null` is a [default for generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), it doesn't mean that provided `T` will allow `null`. Instead you can specify that `null` is allowed for state in addition to `T`:

```
export function useFetch<T>(url: string): [T | null, boolean] {
    const accessToken = useAccessToken();
    const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    // ...
    return [data, isLoading];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAORTo42sCwAUP3QAPSLAbIAdjWAQJxdADF0MKgAsAPABUAfAApkUADYAuOKhhRgEgOYBKUwG1NcAD5wJyQ4aIAjCBENOCQBdRH44CLgqWXM4Lip0VFRNCABrdDkAXjYyf14%20SKiY%20AcAEzwcIgwYABEK0Oy0LFx8LVd3T0M9Dy9bAG5wyOiJWIdgVAAZCBxSq2sq5QBJSenZmwb5bDx0dT8AoL0LZHR%20-kGIpvJKGl1dWzhM7TCCwsjgMjhdeMTktIz7hDnV6FSgqVS6AAGAHocGBgFCAG4ARgAJAgDIZaBCiICXsD8XBVJxSugoKhTLiCVTIgBBZAwVTQYAALzwMgkpghACFOBwoHA0d8kil0hIsQQgdSIrQJXiqbRbJKpQA6BkZW4cVD3R5wTXKgBWqFkd0VcqlcFVRIkunKuAeT0p5vx1TquBtFVOZqdEWqyymMzmujIOEMGE93ul4fxtCBMrgDiFv1FRAxwSjEQ4MAMcjKFSI439a2swQGfFoQA)

Comment: Bless your soul, this saved me hours.